# php post displays empty message and no output

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I am trying to send a group of variables and using PDO to insert into my database, however when i run the page, i get an empty message box and nothing is happening on the page.

This is how I am getting the user inputs.

```
<div class="caption1" contentEditable ="plaintext-only" id="edit1a">
        <P> COMPANY ON AMAZON WANTS YOU TO TEST </BR> AND REVIEW IT’S PRODUCT!</P>
```

index.html

```
<button id="save">Click to Save</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(argument) {
            $('#save').click(function(){
                // Get edit field value
                $edit1a = $('#edit1a').html();
                $edit2a = $('#edit2a').html();
                $edit3a = $('#edit3a').html();
                $edit4a = $('#edit4a').html();
                $edit5a = $('#edit5a').html();
                $edit6a = $('#edit6a').html();
                $edit7a = $('#edit7a').html();
                $edit8a = $('#edit8a').html();
                $edit9a = $('#edit9a').html();
                $edit10a = $('#edit10a').html();
                $edit11a = $('#edit11a').html();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'get.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {edit1: $edit1a, edit2: $edit2a, edit3: $edit3a, edit4: $edit4a, edit5: $edit5a, edit6: $edit6a, edit7: $edit7a, edit8: $edit8a, edit9: $edit9a, edit10: $edit10a, edit11: $edit11a,},
                    datatype: 'html',
                    success: function(rsp){
                            alert(rsp);
                        }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

get.php

```
<?php
//configuration

$host = "localhost";
$name = "lpages";
$user = "root";
$pass = "****";

//connection
$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$name,$user,$pass);

//new data
if(isset($_POST['edit1a'])){
$edit1 = $_POST['edit1a'];
$edit2 = $_POST['edit2a'];
$edit3 = $_POST['edit3a'];
$edit4 = $_POST['edit4a'];
$edit5 = $_POST['edit5a'];
$edit6 = $_POST['edit6a'];
$edit7 = $_POST['edit7a'];
$edit8 = $_POST['edit8a'];
$edit9 = $_POST['edit9a'];
$edit10 = $_POST['edit10a'];
$edit11 = $_POST['edit11a'];
$q      = "INSERT INTO webpages1(edit1, edit2, edit3, edit4, edit5, edit6, edit7, edit8,     edit9, edit10, edit11) 
            values (:edit1, :edit2, :edit3, :edit4, :edit5, :edit6, :edit7, :edit8,     :edit9, :edit10, :edit11);";
            $query = $odb->prepare($q);
            $results = $query->execute(array(
                  ":edit1"=>$edit1,
                  ":edit2"=>$edit2,
              ":edit3"=>$edit3,
              ":edit4"=>$edit4,
              ":edit5"=>$edit5,
              ":edit6"=>$edit6,
              ":edit7"=>$edit7,
              ":edit8"=>$edit8,
              ":edit9"=>$edit9,
              ":edit10"=>$edit10,
              ":edit11"=>$edit11
              ));
        }
        ?>
```

I am fairly new to using PDO so maybe I am having an issue with the formatting

Comment: I think it's something to do with the way you're passing the data `data: {edit1: $edit1a,`.. etc doesn't seem right, can't seem to access the docs atm to help though

Comment: Your php doesnt output any kind of response. Your js probably has errors as well (if those fields are form elements, you would use `.val()` not `.html()`, or better yet `.serialize()` on the form element)

Comment: Ultimatly, if you showed some html markup for the form, you will get a better answer to your question

Comment: It's possible that it could be the variables, I had it working just passing 1 variable using this method, but I was also using just basic msql php. Also the values are not submitted in a form, I'm using ajax to send the variables to get.php.

Comment: I added a line of how I am getting the user inputs. It is a contentEditable field that is stored to an ID.

Comment: @amazingacademy OK, i understand. As i said though, if you dont output something from your php, you wont get anything back in your success function. You havent explained exactly what you do want to happen though

Comment: @amazingacademy IS anything getting saved into the database?

Comment: Steve, nothing is being saved. I'm not even getting an error in the debugger. It is a button click on the main page. I am not wanting to re-direct to a page that says "success" or anything, just click the save button, and it writes the inputs to the database.

Comment: At this point i'm leaning towards the way I am sending the data.  data: edit1: $edit1a,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your POST keys dont match.

You are sending

> {**edit1**: $edit1a, **edit2**: $edit2a,....

But in PHP you retrieve:

> $edit1 = $_POST['**edit1a**'];

It should be `edit1`, `edit2` and so on ...

---

But the most important is to know how to debug:

```
$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$name,$user,$pass);
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

otherwise you are clueless. You can also add more logic with the `$result` value.

for example:

```
if(!$results){
   var_dump($query->error());
   exit();
}
```

As for the undefined value, PHP can tell you if you turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

And of course don't forget to send response back to the ajax call back to determine success.

Comment: {edit1: $edit1a, edit2: $edit2a,.... Bingo! I changed a few other things but no idea why i had missed this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, you are not echoing anything in your PHP.  Try adding:

```
echo "success";
```

At the end of your PHP file.  Then in your JS, you can check:

```
if (rsp == "success") {
    alert("Success inserting into database!");
}
```

Comment: Well the function of this should just insert the data in the database. The save button on the index page does not even redirect the page, just sends the data using ajax

Comment: $query->execute executes the query not so?

Comment: You are correct Rossco, I missed that, oops.  I'll edit.

Comment: @amazingacademy if you expect to show something in the alert, you will need to send a response from php

Comment: Noted, right now I am just using the debugger in google. And nothing is happening once I started using the PDO method